# Equal Symbol giving me problem in batch script

Tags: batch-file

**Equal Character in set replace and replaced giving me problem**
**I just want to change in my js file using Batch Script**

```
@echo off
set "replace=export const baseUrl = "https://abc.pythonanywhere.com/""
set "replaced=// export const baseUrl = "https://abc.pythonanywhere.com/""

set "source=utils.js"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!)
) >>tmp.txt

move tmp.txt %source%
endlocal
exit
```

Comment: Your first two `set` command lines are each missing closing doublequotes.

Comment: I fixed them but still not woring. Any Idea @Compo

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem actually lies with the replacement, which would be constructed as

```
set "line=!line:export const baseUrl = "https://amsproject.pythonanywhere.com/"=// export const baseUrl = "https://amsproject.pythonanywhere.com/"!"
```

So, which `=` is `cmd` supposed to use? To say nothing about the plethora of quotes.

This worked for me:

```
set "onlineswith=export const baseUrl = \"https://amsproject.pythonanywhere.com/\""
set "replace=export"
set "replaced=// export"

set "source=q71141087.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" %source%') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      ECHO %%b|FINDstr /i /L /c:"%onlineswith%" >NUL
      IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 set "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!"
      echo(!line!)
)>tmp.txt

ENDLOCAL
```

I use a unique filename for data so that I can keep all of the relevant data for a question together.

`echo`ing the string read into a `findstr` will set `errorlevel` to 0 if the string is found and 1 if not. The substitution only occurs where the string *IS* detected, so `not errorlevel 1`, and all that is needed is to replace `export` with `// export`.

`findstr` requires backslashes in the string-to-find to escape the quotes.

Note that a single `>` is required to deliver the `echo`ed data to a new file. Using a double `>` *appends* to any current content.

If the file is submitted twice, the `//` will be duplicated on the lines since `// magicstring` contains `magicstring`, so the result is `// // magicstring`

Comment: Its working but also giving me this
**export const getHeaderWithToken = (token, params=null, extra=null) =**

Comment: Without the data that is actually in `utils.js`, it's a guessing game. Add a representative version of `utils.js` by editing your question. Obviously, you should obfuscate any sensitive data - and post say a dozen lines, including the data that should be changed, a few that shouldn't and the lines that's being mangled to produce the result you report.

Comment: ```Utils.js``` only contains baseURL and notify message nothing else is there.

Comment: I have no idea where that string is coming from. It doesn't appear in the batch snippet you posted, and it appears it does not occur in the `utils.js` file either. Is the `utils.js` file being updated correctly?

Comment: Thanks, @Mangoo for helping me, Really appreciate it.